# WCF Client calling a Java Web Service : XmlSerializer cannot find Derived types

Tags: xmlserializer

This seems like a fundamental Web Services problem. However an elegant solution is elusive based on some research I have been able to do. I guess I am missing something here

I am using a WCF client to connect to a External web service of which I have no control. The external WS is java based. There are a bunch of assemblies which are provided to call the methods in web service. These assemblies have base classes and derived classes. The web service methods can take Base class as param whereas from the WCF Client I instantiate a Derived class and pass it to the method.

To simulate this scenario, I created a small project with one ClassLibrary which has a BaseClass and a DerivedClass with one method.

Then I create an asmx web service and add a HelloWorld method inside it. I add a reference to the ClassLibrary. This method takes a BaseClass type param.

Then I create a Service Reference to the ASMX web service. In the proxy class, I add a XmlSerializerFormatAttribute to the method if it is already not there.

From the WCF client, I call the ASMX web method

**BaseClass bc = new Derived();**

**ServiceReference1.TestService ts = new WCFTest.ServiceReference1.TestService();**

**lbl1.Text = (c1.HelloWorld(bc));**

The call fails with error
*The type ClassLib.Derived was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.*

The only way I could call this web service method was by adding XmlInclude attribute to the BaseClass in the ClassLibrary. 
In my scenario, this library is a dll provided by an external vendor. I cannot add attributes to its classes. I have looked a DataContractSerializer and KnownTypes and XmlSerializer ctor. However those solutions do not seem to be applicable in my scenario.

How can I make XMLSerializer see the Derived classes in the assemblies I have referencing in the WCF Client? Is there an elegant solution?

Thanks,
Hem

Answer (score 0):

Including your own type mapping for an XmlSerializerOperationBehavior may just work, but I haven't tried this (see GetXmlMappings).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.xmlserializeroperationbehavior.aspx

Alternatively, forcing use of the DataContractSerializer via a DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior (as opposed to the XmlSerializerOperationBehavior it's using now) may work too, if you specify your own known types

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Finally, as a last resort, you can force use of the DataContractSerializer using the DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior, then specify your own DataContractSurrogate to force use of the XmlSerializer where you can pass custom types to its constructor (which circumvents the requirement for the XmlInclude attribute).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751540.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll take a look at these options. Thanks